# I am trying to do a BlogPosting Schema Markup. I don't know whats wrong with it

Tags: json, seo, json-ld

Why is this json-ld markup not being picked up by Structured Data Testing Tool by Google? I am not sure where the syntax error is.

```
   <script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", 
 "@type": "BlogPosting",
 "headline": "Brain and Head Injury after Cycling Accident",
 "image": "https://www.utahadvocates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Traumaticbraininjury2010-1.jpg",
  "logo": "https://www.utahadvocates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/final_advocates_logo-compressed.png",
 "editor": "Jen Carrigan", 
 "genre": "Personal Injury", 
 "keywords": "Brain Injury, Personal Injury, Cycling Accident ", 
 "publisher": "The Advocates",
 "url": "https://www.utahadvocates.com",
 "datePublished": "2016-06-30",
 "dateCreated": "2016-06-30",
 "dateModified": "2015-09-20",
 "description": "Head and brain injuries can occur when you are in a cycling accident. Studies show that these types of injuries can lead to much slower reaction times. ",
 "articleBody": "Brain and head injuries occur after cycling accidents overwhelmingly in cases where the cyclist was not wearing a helmet at the time of the collision. In addition, brain injuries occur significantly more when the cyclist was hit by a motor vehicle as opposed to any other type of cycling accident. The symptoms from these types of brain and head injuries can last significantly longer than you would think. Let’s take a look at some of these symptoms below.",

   "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Jen Carrigan "
             }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "picked up"? Google’s SDTT seems to parse this fine.

Comment: Use Google tool to see what is wrong https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ (4 errors)

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues with the markup snippet you have shared.

1. Image attribute - [`schema.org/BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) image permits `ImageObject` and `URL`, however, Google only permits [`ImageObject`](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#article_types)
2. Logo attribute - The logo attribute is a child of the `Publisher`, not of the `BlogPosting`. So use an object with type `Organization` for the publisher attribute.
3. Add `mainEntityOfPage`, it is required.

See bellow -

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{  
   "@context":"http://schema.org",
   "@type":"BlogPosting",
   "headline":"Brain and Head Injury after Cycling Accident",
   "image":{  
      "@type":"ImageObject",
      "url":"https://www.utahadvocates.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Traumaticbraininjury2010-1.jpg",
      "height":2260,
      "width":2841
   },
   "editor":"Jen Carrigan",
   "genre":"Personal Injury",
   "keywords":"Brain Injury, Personal Injury, Cycling Accident ",
   "publisher":{  
      "@type":"Organization",
      "name":"The Advocates",
      "logo":{  
         "@type":"ImageObject",
         "url":"https://www.utahadvocates.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/final_advocates_logo-compressed.png",
         "width":300,
         "height":60
      }
   },
   "url":"https://www.utahadvocates.com",
   "datePublished":"2016-06-30",
   "dateCreated":"2016-06-30",
   "dateModified":"2015-09-20",
   "description":"Head and brain injuries can occur when you are in a cycling accident. Studies show that these types of injuries can lead to much slower reaction times. ",
   "articleBody":"Brain and head injuries occur after cycling accidents overwhelmingly in cases where the cyclist was not wearing a helmet at the time of the collision. In addition, brain injuries occur significantly more when the cyclist was hit by a motor vehicle as opposed to any other type of cycling accident. The symptoms from these types of brain and head injuries can last significantly longer than you would think. Let’s take a look at some of these symptoms below.",
   "author":{  
      "@type":"Person",
      "name":"Jen Carrigan "
   },
   "mainEntityOfPage":{  
      "@type":"WebPage",
      "@id":"https://www.utahadvocates.com/"
   }
}</script>
```